# Monitoring Informatica Java processes with JConsole on Windows Server 2008

Tags: monitoring, java

I am having an issue getting JConsole to connect to my Java processes. Let's start with the basics...

### Java Version

As you can tell from the path below, we are running Informatica with packaged Java.

```
E:\Informatica\9.1.0\java\bin>java.exe -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
```

### Java Processes

Our java processes are spawned from a windows service run as "UserX". Here are two of the process commands as shown by `wmic process list`.

- E:\Informatica\9.1.0\java\bin\java -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 -Xmx512M -classpath E:\Informatica\9.1.0\services\shared\jars\infatomcatbootstrap.jar;E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\temp_AdminConsole -Dcatalina.home=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\temp_AdminConsole\temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\temp_AdminConsole\conf\logging.properties -DINFA_HOME=E:\Informatica\9.1.0 -DINFA_DOMAINS_FILE=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\domains.infa -Duser.dir=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\bin -Dcom.informatica.imf.encryption.provider=com.informatica.imf.icore.impl.IEncryptionProviderImpl -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager com.informatica.isp.tools.tomcatstarter.InfaTomcatBootstrap start
- E:\Informatica\9.1.0\java\bin\java -Xmx4096m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -classpath E:\Informatica\9.1.0\services\shared\jars\infatomcatbootstrap.jar;E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\temp\AS_GProd -Dcatalina.home=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\temp\AS_GProd\temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\temp\AS_GProd\conf\logging.properties -DINFA_HOME=E:\Informatica\9.1.0 -DINFA_DOMAINS_FILE=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\domains.infa -Duser.dir=E:\Informatica\9.1.0\tomcat\bin -Dcom.informatica.imf.encryption.provider=com.informatica.imf.icore.impl.IEncryptionProviderImpl -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager com.informatica.isp.tools.tomcatstarter.InfaTomcatBootstrap start

### The Problem

When I open JConsole (as UserX), I see all my Java processes, but they are grayed out with a message of  ***The management agent is not enabled on this process***. I understand the meaning of the message, but I do **not** understand **why the management agent is not running**. My understanding is that all Java SE 6+ processes have an "attachable" management agent by default and that manually turning it on is not necessary. What am I missing?

### Side note about getting JConsole working

Not sure if this is relevant, but I am connecting to the machine remotely, and our Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Temporary folders group policy is configured so that I get a unique temp directory. Eg: Temp\2 or Temp\3. I have to changed this to Temp\ in a terminal and launch JConsole from that terminal in order for JConsole to find the pid files that the JMV spits out.